# Cut out surplus material

Tags: modeling

I have a quick question. Looking at the next GIF that I made, what is the quickier way you can come up with to delete the excess material that goes beyond the wall? It is basically the attachment of the handrail to the wall what is giving me this "problem".

[image: handrail-attachment]

My solution would be using the boolean modifier with a cube or something, so obviously I know how to do it. But I'm looking for the best solution, i.e., does Blender let me select the excess material in any way? For example, is there a quick way to intersect those planes? I read about intersecting planes in Blender and seems like a difficult task (not worth it in this case). So I discarded that solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a game asset? Why do you want to remove those parts? Are they visible from the outside?

Comment: Thanks for asking @metaphor_set. Yes, it is a game asset. No, it is not visible from the outside. But I like to keep my models as clean as possible, so I thought it was worth it. Maybe to grow my knowledge!

Comment: I know what you mean. Sometimes merging topology isn't worth all the effort, since it's not necessarily make the the topology cleaner. And of course it adds a lot of geometry to your model. I'd go for the submesh solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boolean operations would work well in this case.

Alternatively you could also use the *Knife Project* operator on your mesh. It basically uses the outline of another object (mesh or curve) and cuts the editing mesh through its silhouette.

It's workflows goes like:

1. Select object to be cut
2. Enter *Edit Mode* on the object to be cut
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and select 'knife object' (cutting shape)
4. Adjust the view accordingly, the cutting process is view based (dependent on the current viewport view angle and perspective mode), if desired switch to orthographic *User View* with <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> for an undistorted true size cut.
5. Go to the menu Mesh > Knife Project
6. Tick the option *Cut Through* so all faces are cut, even the background ones
7. Select the remaining geometry and manually delete it.

For Blender 2.79 and previous

1. Select 'knife object' (cutting shape)
2. Select object to be cut (without deselecting the previous one)
3. Enter *Edit Mode* on the object to be cut
4. Adjust the view accordingly, the cutting process is view based (dependent on the current viewport view angle and perspective mode), if desired switch to orthographic *User View* with <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> for an undistorted true size cut.
5. Open the <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> menu and call the operator *Knife Project*
6. Tick the option *Cut Through* so all faces are cut, even the background ones
7. Select the remaining geometry and manually delete it.

[image]

Comment: Hey Duarte, thank you so much!! I didn't know this tool. I knew there had to be a way, thanks again! :)