# How to remove the face that intersects throught the cylinder

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects

[image]

I need to remove the face inside this cylinder intersecting with my cube. I've tried to use the knife, project knife with a circle, tried adding a boolean and union/intersect.. nothing does it. The cylinder is scaled down towards the bottom and there is also an angle to the cube. still not working. Please help ! and all those object are currently a single piece.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63719/cut-out-surplus-material/63721#63721