# How to remove a protrusion from a surface?

Tags: objects

Let's say I have a head object and a sword object.  I move the sword so that it is placed through the head.  The part of the sword that is sticking out of the other side of the head I want to delete.  The rest of the sword, including that part inside the head and the contact points between sword and head inside, I want to keep.  How do I do that?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63719/cut-out-surplus-material

Comment: That's only if the surface is flat though (I think).  What if the object protrudes out of an irregular surface?

Comment: I can't believe I'm recommending this, but look into Booleans. And be very careful about how you use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what everyone's talking about with Booleans: The Boolean modifier.
[image]
[image]

using the "difference" operation, wherever the sword object intersects the cube object, its volume is excluded.

Here's what it looks like without the head:
[image]

The surface of the volume you subtract from the sword can be as complex as you need; you could use the head object, for example. Be careful though because the boolean modifier is computationally expensive and prone to error. Stick to simple, unsbdivided manifold meshes with only one part to them for the best chance of success.

Edit: Here's the .blend file :[image]

Comment: @ dixiepig   Great!  I need the sword inside the head as well.  But I think I can modify your idea.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding right I would delete the part of the sword model you don't want. Then selecting all the edges that make up the new open loop and  Select Make face/fill it to fill the hole by making that whole new face. Then reposition sword.

Comment: The challenge is making that open loop match the irregular surface perfectly, something along the lines of Booleans.  Like get exterior of head, intersect with sword, delete intersection.  But I don't quite get the commands.