# Tips on cutting

Tags: modeling

Has anyone got any tips on how to perfectly cut away everything outside the pink line. Im thinking that project knife is my friend but I need to align the edges of the knife perfectly.

[image]

Any help you be appreciated.

Comment: Using the knife, use the C key (angle constraint) to have horizontal or vertical alignment. Knife shortcuts and options are displayed in the bottom status bar.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63719/cut-out-surplus-material/63721 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77279/projection-geometry-example/77281#77281

Answer (score 1):

Use a single plane and a *Knife Project* tool.
You can align it rather easily using Vertex Snapping.

1. Enable *Snapping to Vertex*, and set it to *Closest*
2. Use the move tool to move the edges
3. Use the Mouse cursor to control which vertex it snaps to

[image]

Comment: Hmm I cannot seem to get it to snap :-(  Did you select both the plane and the grid below before going into edit mode
https://www.dropbox.com/s/q056ugjtfm49g2t/square.blend?dl=0

Comment: Hello :). Make sure the snapping is *Enabled* (the magnet icon is blue). It works just fine in your file.

Comment: Just had to hold my mouse while moving.

Comment: Glad it works for you :). Feel free to mark the answer as accepted **✓** so others can easily find it.