# Cut an imported obj

Tags: obj

Good morning

I have imported a obj with textures in blender and i would like to cut it and eliminate margins. in the image you can see several trees in margins, and i would like to cut and only remain the area of the green square. How can i do this?

Thanks[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63719/cut-out-surplus-material https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77279/projection-geometry-example https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/how-would-you-cut-a-shape-out-of-an-object-using-another-object

Answer (score 0):

Make a cube the size of the green square, add a boolean modifier to your mesh and use the cube as the target object, set it to intersect.

For example:

All this is done from the top view, <kbd>7</kbd> on the numpad

This represents your imported .obj mesh:
[image]

Add a cube:
[image]

Scale the cube to the size you need. Hit <kbd>S</kbd> to scale, then hit <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd> to scale on the X or Y axis... Try it out.
[image]

Next add the modifier to your base mesh, in your case you need the Boolean modifier. Change it to "Intersect" then click the little eyedropper and select the cube as the "Object"
[image]

Then hide the cube and your base mesh should have been trimmed into the shape of your green square.
[image]

Appologies for the poor quality of the gifs, each gif can only be 2Mb max... :)

You can "apply" the modifier so it is no longer modifiable if you like.
[image]

Please click the tick next to this answer if it works for you so others can find this information. If you need more help, just ask! :)

Comment: Thanks Psyonic. Could you explain a bit detailed? it is the first time i use blender

Comment: No worries, I'll update my answer with some pics and vids :)

Comment: @JuanL I've updated my answer, I hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks! I have performed this correctly. However, when i export to gltf there is a remain of the cube with image textures . could it be removed?

Comment: In the export window, on the right there should be a drop-down called "Include", make sure you have "Limit to Selected Objects" ticked and only have the object you want to export selected.

Comment: Yes, this is what i do, but after apply boolean interset, the a part of the cube remains as part of the object, it is like a fussion, it does not dissapear completelly and takes the textures of the object

Comment: In https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215391/replace-textures-with-text-in-faces you have the example, check below the building the remain of the cube basis.

Comment: Since this answered your original question, please mark it as correct so others can find it. I'll try to help you in your new question.