# Replace textures with text in faces

Tags: obj

I have cut an obj with a cube using a boolean intersection but when I exported it in the surfaces of the cube appear images of textures as you can see in image. Could be possible to delete, replace, paint these images and write a text (for example copyright) or a solid color?

Thanks for your help

[image: image with textures in cube]

Comment: Are you looking for a procedural way of doing this? Or are you happy to simply edit the obj and delete the faces?

Comment: I have tried to delete the faces but i couldnot find any way for this. so i have the idea of change the textures and paint a copyright and the location of building. any idea is welcome

Comment: Can you share your .blend file so we can check out what can be done? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: it is 96 mb you can find it in https://www.asturnatura.com/3dmodel/conventin/conventin.blend Thanks for your help