# How do I cut a hole in a face

Tags: faces

[image]

I'm using blender to design a paper model house. I'm using the export -> paper model add on.
In the image below, I have a cuboid chimney running up through a roof. How do I make a matching hole in the roof face? Thanks!

Comment: or boolean modifier

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/how-would-you-cut-a-shape-out-of-an-object-using-another-object https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63719/cut-out-surplus-material

Comment: I've added an answer in the link given by Duarte that may fit your needs if the chimney mesh is part of the same object