# Cutting off excess plane

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]

I have this shape that is made from 4 bezier curves and then exstruded. How can I cut of the excess plane so im left with just the shape?

Comment: Close the shape and use the Boolean modifier?

Comment: knife project may be more simple

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63719/cut-out-surplus-material https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve

Comment: In this _particular_ case, an X _Screw_ modifier with 4 segments (on a single, unextruded curve) will do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it manually without the *Boolean* modifier and the existing mesh you already have, you can use the following method - probably not as elegant as Markus' solution, but I think the *Split Edges & Faces* option deserves more attention in modeling:

1. In *Edit Mode*, enable *Auto Merge* with the option *Split Edges & Faces*.

   [image: auto merge]
2. Now select all vertices by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> to move the vertices by 0 m, left-click or <kbd>Return</kbd> to confirm. Afterwards the faces are split along the intersections.

   [image: split faces]
3. If you then select the outer edges on one side and press <kbd>G</kbd> twice, you can edge slide them towards the faces until they meet the inner vertices. Left-click or <kbd>Return</kbd> to confirm the slide, with the *Auto Merge* option still enabled they are now merged together.

   [image: edge slide to face]

   [image: faces split on edges]
4. Repeat this for the other sides and then you have the desired shape.

   [image: finished shape]

Answer (score 2):

In your case extrusions are axis-aligned, and the beziers are rotated 2D curves, so you can take advantage of 3D beziers interpolating each axis independently, and just copying one axis to the other - remember to make the handles "FREE" otherwise moving one handle will move another and you won't be able to repeat the step on the opposite handle…

[image]

Now you can apply a "Screw" modifier with a resolution of 4:

[image]

[image]